# The order of events in "Plus de projets Rush : des QCM à la place" ?

Tags: négation

I am studying a French test exam and really cannot understand the below phrase:

**Plus de projets Rush : des QCM à la place**

MCQ is used as a replacement for Rush

or

In addition to Rush, there is a MCQ.

or

First Rush and then MCQ

Rush is a type of exam in that question.

MCQ: multi choice question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plus de projets Rush : des QCM à la place

"Plus de" could be transtaled as "more" or as "not any more"/"no more"

here, only the context and what the sentence means can guide you...

My personal guess is:
"No more Rush projects : QCM (tests) instead"

Note: in fact, when "plus" means "no more" it should be used with a negation like "ne".
je **ne** veux **plus** de projets Rush.
I do **not** want Rush projects **any more**.

But many times, french speaking people use a "shortcut" like :
**plus** de projets Rush.
when speaking casually or if you want to have a strong slogan/title

To complete my answer
"En plus de" means "in addition of"